# SQL - Group By based on sequence - Oracle/Postgre

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, group-by, sequence

I need some help. 
To perform a `group by` based on a sequence.
I'm using Oracle or Postgres.

I have the following scenario. The `ID_SEQ` is based on `equip_id`, `Day` and `Stat`. Creating a sequence.

I need to group the intervals between these sequences.

Example:

```
EQUIP_ID    DAY         STAT    DATE              ID_SEQ
JSTD123     19/06/2017  ON      19/06/2017 16:39    1
JSTD123     19/06/2017  OFF     19/06/2017 16:41    1
JSTD123     01/07/2017  ON      01/07/2017 13:50    1
JSTD123     01/07/2017  OFF     01/07/2017 13:51    1
JSTD123     01/07/2017  OFF     01/07/2017 14:40    2
JSTD123     01/07/2017  ON      01/07/2017 15:20    1
JSTD123     01/07/2017  ON      01/07/2017 15:20    2
JSTD123     01/07/2017  ON      01/07/2017 15:22    3
JSTD123     01/07/2017  ON      01/07/2017 15:22    4
JSTD123     01/07/2017  ON      01/07/2017 15:23    5
JSTD123     01/07/2017  ON      01/07/2017 15:26    6
JSTD123     01/07/2017  ON      01/07/2017 15:26    7
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
EQUIP_ID    DATE         STAT   START               END
JSTD123     19/06/2017   ON     19/06/2017 16:39    19/06/2017 16:39
JSTD123     19/06/2017   OFF    19/06/2017 16:41    19/06/2017 16:41
JSTD123     01/07/2017   ON     01/07/2017 13:50    01/07/2017 13:50
JSTD123     01/07/2017   OFF    01/07/2017 13:51    01/07/2017 14:40
JSTD123     01/07/2017   ON     01/07/2017 15:20    01/07/2017 15:26
```

I can't get a similar output.

Comment: "I need to group the intervals between these sequences."  I don't get it.  What does `ID_SEQ` have to do with this?

Comment: I don't think group by makes sense, here. Your end report currently shows the data filtered on ID_SEQ = 1.

Maybe you intend to sort by ID_SEQ (and some other columns based upon your preference).

Comment: Also, what SQL have you tried to get the desired output? You need to provide more information.

Comment: lots of island and gap problems today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. Grouping consecutive rows with the same stat on a given day and getting the min date and max date of that group.

The logic is to assign groups by getting the previous value of stat (per equip_id and day) using `lag` and then using a running sum to reset when a new stat value is encountered. After this group assignment is done, you can just use `group by` to get the min and max date per equip_id,stat,day and grp.

```
SELECT equip_id,
       day,
       stat,
       min(date),
       max(date)
FROM
  (SELECT t.*,
          sum(col) over(partition BY equip_id,day ORDER BY date) AS grp
   FROM
     (SELECT t.*,
      CASE WHEN stat=lag(stat) over(partition BY equip_id,day ORDER BY date) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS col
      FROM t
      ) t
   ) t
GROUP BY equip_id,day,stat,grp
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/XRSJZ99563)

Comment: That's almost what I need. But you've given me an idea of how to solve it. Thank you.